# Prove some facts about a sequence of functions?

Tags: sequence-of-function

I have this simple sequence of functions:
$$f_{n}(x)=\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

I want to see if I can correctly:

1. Prove that $f_{n}\in\ L^{1}(0,+\infty)$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$.
2. Prove that $f_{n}\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ pointwise in $(0,+\infty)$
3. Prove that $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f_{n}(x)dx \rightarrow0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

   ---

So, starting from **point one**:
I see that $f_{n}\in C^{0}(0+\infty)$.

I have to study $|f_{n}|$ in $U(0^{+})$ and in $U(+\infty)$.

In $U(0^{+})$,

$|f_{n}|\approx \frac{nx}{nx^{\frac{3}{2}}}\approx  x^{-\frac{3}{2}+1}\approx x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

I think this prove that $f_{n}\in L^{1}(U(0^{+}))$ because it gives an integrable function.

In $U(+\infty)$ I think that $|f{n}|\rightarrow0$ (I just computet the limit). So, this should be fine with the hypothesis.

---

**Point two**

$f_{n}$ it's a bounded function and for $n\rightarrow\infty$ is easy to see that $f_{n}\rightarrow0$ , $n \rightarrow \infty$ and poinwise on $(0,+\infty)$.

---

**Point three**

As I have said above "by eyes" I would say that the hypothesis is right but I hav esome difficult to put it on more detailled "math language". Could someone help me and help me on my work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prove that a function $f$ is an element of $L^1(0,\infty)$, one must prove the following:
$$\int_0^{\infty} |f(x)| \;\mathrm{d}x < \infty$$
So, in your case, observe that we have two ways to bound the sine:
$$|\sin(nx)| \leq nx \qquad \text{and} \qquad |\sin(nx)| \leq 1$$
Observe that on $(0,\frac1n)$, the left bound is better, whereas on $(\frac1n,\infty)$, the right one is tighter. Hence, by splitting up the integral, we obtain for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty} |f_n(x)| \;\mathrm{d}x &= \int_0^{\infty} \left|
\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx^{3/2}}\right| \;\mathrm{d}x \leq \int_0^{\frac1n} \frac{nx}{nx^{3/2}} \;\mathrm{d} x + \int_{\frac1n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nx^{3/2}} \;\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_0^{\frac1n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \;\mathrm{d}x + \frac{1}{n} \int_{\frac1n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}} \;\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \left[2\sqrt{x}\right]_0^{\frac1n} + \frac{1}{n}\left[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\right]_{\frac1n}^{\infty} = 2\sqrt{\frac1n} + \frac{2\sqrt{n}}{n} \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{4}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{align*}
So, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we find that the integral is finite, as $4/\sqrt{n} < \infty$. This proves claim one. And moreover, as $4/\sqrt{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, we have proven claim three as well.

Now, can you do the remaining second claim in a rigorous way? Hint, choose $x \in (0,\infty)$ arbitrarily, and go from there.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply. I'm thinking about this idea: I know that
$$-\frac{1}{nx^{3/2}}\le\sin(nx)\le \frac{1}{nx^{3/2}}$$
And
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}-\frac{1}{nx^{3/2}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{nx^{3/2}}=0$$

Wich (should) prove that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ with $f=0$ on $\mathbb R$.
Is this another way to prove claim $1$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Nope, it does not hold that $-\frac{1}{nx^{3/2}} \leq \sin(nx) \leq \frac{1}{nx^{3/2}}$ for all natural $n$ and real $x$. Take for example $n = 1$ and $x = \frac12\pi$.

Comment: Ah, you probably meant:
$$-\frac{1}{nx^{3/2}} \leq \frac{\sin(nx)}{nx^{3/2}} \leq \frac{1}{nx^{3/2}}$$
This does indeed show that $f_n \to 0$ pointwise on $(0,\infty)$. Sadly, pointwise convergence to an $L^1$-function is not sufficient to prove that the functions themselves are in $L^1$. For this, one usually has to rely on the more elementary calculation of the integral, like I did in the main answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Ok, so I think that this prove well claim $2$ instead of claim $1$.

Comment: Yes, it does prove claim 2. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know by chance a source of exercises on this topic, so that I can do more practice and improve my skills? It's very important for me! Thank you again! :).

Comment: No problem. :) I must admit that I do not know any source of exercises on this topic, but perhaps another question, indicating what kind of exercises you're looking for, will help you find what you want. :p

Comment: I'll try to follow your advice. Thank you so much. :).

Comment: Hi and thank you for your work. I have retry this exercise and I have understood all the steps, but one more doubt: why you have choosed $(0,1/n)$ for the left bound for the sine? Thank you. :).

Comment: As for all x in (0,1/n), nx < 1, and hence on this interval, the left bound is smaller (and hence better). :)

Answer (score 0):

- Note that $|\sin(nx)|\leq \min\{xn,1\}$ for all $x\geq 0$. Thus
  $$\int_0^\infty\left|\frac{\sin (nx)}{nx^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right|dx\leq\int_0^1x^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx+\frac{1}{n}\int_1^\infty x^{-\frac{3}{2}}dx=2+\frac{2}{n}<\infty.$$
  This proves $f_n\in L^1(0,\infty)$.
- It's trivial that $|f_n(x)|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.
- As shown in the first claim, we have
  $$|f_n(x)|\leq \frac{nx}{nx^{\frac{3}{2}}}\chi_{[0,1]}(x)+\frac{1}{nx^{\frac{3}{2}}}\chi_{[1,\infty)}(x)\leq x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\chi_{[0,1]}(x)+x^{-\frac{3}{2}}\chi_{[1,\infty)}(x),$$
  so $f_n$ is uniformly bounded by an integrable function. The last claim now follows right away by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your reply. I want to ask you if you know some sources where I can find some exercises about this stuff to improve mi skills and reasoning. Thank you :).